# Cursor clock and thread priority

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, cursor

I work on something that consumes a bit too much CPU from time to time for background tasks. I want to lower thread priority or something like that so the nagging cursor clock dont show up.
I tried with

```
SetThreadPriority
```

but it doesn't helps really, i found something else, if my application shows GUI, cursor clock wont be shown on heavy CPU tasks, if it works in background it will show.

Can someone explain that ?

Comment: Do you use a worker (non-GUI) thread for background tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform heavy computational operation in a worker thread, leaving the main/GUI thread free to interact with the OS (receive messages) than the cursor will not change.

The Windows OS changes the cursor when an application is not responsive (doesn't receive/process window messages).

Comment: So can i handle these messages without GUI ?